# How can I identify the methods touched in HG changset?

Tags: python, mercurial

I would like a way to list all of the python methods which were touched between two mercurial changesets.  Is there a tool available which will easily do this?

Clarification based on comment:

I am not looking for something 100% comprehensive.  If the tool could identify each line changed in the diff, then which method/class it falls within, that would be great.

Comment: If "affected by" includes metaprogramming like decorators and dynamically created classes (which would be very useful), then it's virtually impossible except perhaps by importing the code.

Comment: @delnan I realize that something completely comprehensive is too much to ask.  Please see the edit to my question.

Comment: why not simply grep the diff for class/def?

Comment: @goncalopp: because that won't work unless the `class` or `def` statement or the lines right next to them were changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any tools to do this but it should be doable with a custom solution
It depends on how complex a solution you'd like to go for.

Here's two possible solutions without too much detail:
Solution 1: Do a diff between the changesets and make sure your hg diff command has lots of context in it (the -U option), then have a simple script that searches from changes lines up to the nearest function definition (a simple regex should do)

Solution 2:
Parse the diff as above for the change line numbers (for example @@ -7,6 +7,10 @@ ) and then write an introspection tool that tells you which function that line comes from. Obviously this can get quite complex but here's a very simple approximation:

```
    import sys

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import foo
        f_list = []
        in_line = int(sys.argv[1])
        for k,v in sys.modules['foo'].__dict__.iteritems():
            if k.startswith('__'):
                continue
            if hasattr(v, '__call__'): #We have a function
                f_list.append((v.__name__, v.__code__.co_firstlineno))
        #sort our function list according to starting line of each function (if needed)
        last_fn = None
        for f_name, f_line in f_list:
            if f_line >= in_line:
                break;
            else:
                last_fn = f_name

        if last_fn:
                print 'Line {} is probably in function {}'.format(in_line, last_fn)
```

Here I'm just looking in the module foo but that can be changed to whatever module you need.
I'm not going to paste the contents of my module, so you'll have to trust me that it works :)

```
    ./intro.py 7 
    Line 7 is probably in function do_foo

    ./intro.py 13
    Line 13 is probably in function do_blah
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Option 2 is basically what I had in mind. When I get a little more time, I will implement something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the "current method" obviously depends on the file's language, so you're not going to find a ready solution in the mercurial commandset. But it's not too hard to scan a python file manually, and track the current class and method (as long as the code doesn't play games with the syntax). You did say you don't need it to be bullet-proof, right?

If one of the changesets being compared is an ancestor of the other, you should get pretty good mileage out of `hg annotate` (a.k.a. `hg blame`), which tells you when each line in your file was last touched. You can then scan files for recent changes, while at the same time keeping track of the current class and method or function.

If the changesets have a more complex relationship, you may have to do some work: Run a diff between the two versions, and parse the diff output for a list of file-line pairs that have changed; then scan the source files to figure out the class and method that contains each change. (Alternately, you could pre-process the source files to build an index, *then* review the diffs).